# Err "bad proposal response 500" when trying to join channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have the following structure : one orderer, one ca and one peer. A channel1 is define and the peer has successfully joined this channel. A first chaincode has been successfully deployed on the peer. The chaincode has been written using composer, export as a .bna, installed and start on the described structure using a connection profile (json)

I am trying to ask a second peer to join the previously created channel using the following command : "peer channel join -b channel1.block"

but I get the following error : 
"Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500)"

Complete error from peer's log :

ERRO 01c [][997ac53c] simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode name:"cscc"  response status 500 for txid: 997ac*****

The command "peer channel fetch newest" has been issued before with success.

Any idea for me please ?

Comment: This error comes when , channel is already joined. Pls check logs

Comment: Another peer has already joined the channel but not the concerned one it's new one I just installed .... On the peer which is already part of the channel there is already a chaincode deployed, can it be the problem ?

Comment: What can I found in the log ?

Comment: "peer channel list" command does not return anything ....

Answer (score 1):

So if I try to deploy my new peer on the same virtual machine, it react the same BUT the error message is not exactly the same ( why ??), here I still error 500 but more details : 
2018-08-21 13:38:30.435 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: "JoinChain" for chainID = channel1 failed because of validation of configuration block, because of Bad configuration envelope: Not a tx of type [CONFIG]))

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now FIXED !!
The command "peer channel fetch newest" must be replaced by "peer channel fetch config" Check the following link for more info :
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/commands/peerchannel.html

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same question.In my case, using

```
peer channel fetch 0 mychannel.block -c mychannel --orderer orderer.zee.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/zee.com/orderers/orderer.zee.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.zee.com-cert.pem
```

would help, that is, we need the first block to join (sequence number 0), not the newest or config.
Here is my post :[Get the error:Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500) when I try to join a peer to an existed channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332530/get-the-errorerror-proposal-failed-err-bad-proposal-response-500-when-i-try)