# Get the error:Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500) when I try to join a peer to an existed channel?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I tried to get the newest block from an exist channel by:

```
peer channel fetch newest mychannel.block -c mychannel --orderer orderer.zee.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/zee.com/orderers/orderer.zee.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.zee.com-cert.pem
```

then I got mychannel.block in current directory.
Using this block I applied

```
peer channel join -b mychannel.block --orderer orderer.zee.com:7050\
```

I expected to join that channel(before that I already checked this peer is not in the channel list by call `peer channel list`).
But an error printed out:

```
2018-09-14 12:43:30.931 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 03b ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2018-09-14 12:43:30.931 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4204cba90, CONNECTING
2018-09-14 12:43:30.945 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 03d pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4204cba90, READY
2018-09-14 12:43:30.945 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 03e Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-09-14 12:43:30.946 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 03f Sign: plaintext: 0AAC070A5C08011A0C08F2D9EEDC0510...5DC121D0F96F65155F0CC2910A000A00 
2018-09-14 12:43:30.946 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 040 Sign: digest: A8A7A0AA46CC2B9F3683C6EA22C2B6175B2682AB9CF87A94552A8A62A8C8432E 
Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500)
root@22ad397fad46:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer#
```

Comment: Thanks if anyone can release some useful notes.

Comment: I've checked the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837690/err-bad-proposal-response-500-when-trying-to-join-channel, but none of those answers give my question a solution.

Comment: Found the answer, using 

    peer channel fetch 0 mychannel.block -c mychannel --orderer orderer.zee.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/zee.com/orderers/orderer.zee.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.zee.com-cert.pem

would help, that is, we need the first block to join (sequence number 0), not the newest or config.